# im writing a plugin for a python app, find i can't load any external library

Tags: python, plugins, import, external

im writing a plugin for a python app, find i can't load any external library...
This python app has its own small library set and doesn't search python26 folder for other libraries.thus I found that its difficult to import any external libraries (such as python-twitter) in my plugin script..by the way, im not allowed to modify that python app, so i need to add some code in my plugin script to load those external libraries...and more fun, most libraries call other libraries...i found a way to load one library but still got error when this lib call other libs...tried to add PYTHONPATH='C:/Python26/Lib/site-packages/' in front of my script, not really works....

Answer (score 1):

you can add locations to the python path as below..and add this in your plugin before it's main code

```
import sys
sys.path.append('your path')
```

or

```
sys.path.insert(0,"your path")
```

[Modifying Python’s Search Path](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path)